# Port Unreachable when using Datagram Channel

Tags: java, networking, nio, datagram, channel

While using Datagram Channel I get a `PortUnreachableException`. This is what my Codes look like :
This is the sender side

```
//Open a non-blocking socket to send data to Receiver
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.configureBlocking(false);
channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(10000));
channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host,UDPort));
```

It is this code that gives me : `java.net.PortUnreachableException`. The parameter "host" is set as:

```
String host = new String("192.168.1.3");
```

The Receiver side is this

```
//Open a Socket to listen for incoming data
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(UDPort));
channel.configureBlocking(false);
ByteBuffer buffer =   ByteBuffer.allocate((recvpkt[0].length)*4);
System.out.println("Waiting for packet");
channel.receive(buffer);
System.out.println("Received packet");
```

I cannot understand why I am getting this exception. I have looked up examples on net and this is how they all suggest the code should be.

UPDATE 1:

As pointed out in the comment by shazin, the binding needs to be done at Receiver and connection at Sender. The updated code for Sender is:

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.configureBlocking(false);
channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host,UDPort));
```

For the Receiver:

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.configureBlocking(false);
channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(host,UDPort));
```

Now the problem is that if "host" is set as "localhost" the program works but if we pass an IP say 10.132.0.30 as "host" the `java.net.PortUnreachableException` occurs. While the `channel.isConnected()` option return "true" the channel.write(buffer) command gives an Exception.

UPDATE 2:

The `PortUnreachableException` is now gone. The only difference in the code now is that I am using selectors to accept connections on the Receiver side. I still do not understand why the error came when selectors were not being used. If anyone stumbles on this question and knows, do post your answer.

Comment: What is the value for UDPort? And why are you binding the sender? You should bind the reciever and connect from the sender isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I removed the binding from the sender side and carried it out on the receiver side. The connection now occurs but there is a caveat. It connects if "host" is set as "localhost" not "192.168.1.3". Why does an IP address not connect. Does IP address need to be passed in a format other than String ?

Comment: Seems like you are testing both sender and receiver in the same machine. Are you sure the about the IP of the machine?

Comment: Yeah currently testing on same machine. Found IP using ifconfig. So should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following to get the Ip Address

```
channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host),UDPort));
```

UDPort must be equal to the port you are using to Bind in Receiver.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct but the port really is unreachable. It's a network connectivity problem, or a no-listener problem, not a coding problem.

Comment: Thnx for the reply. I just tried out setting the host string as "localhost" instead of "192.168.1.3". In that case, the connection occurs. Any thoughts on why an IP address fails but a name works ? Because when I do connect to a remote machine, I will need to pass in the IP address of that machine.

Comment: 'The connection occurs' but does the data get through? Fundamentally either the IP address is unreachable - check with `ping(1)` - or nothing is listening at that port.

Comment: The data goes through correctly in case "localhost" is passed as "host" instead of the IP address. But when an actual IP address is used, I get the java.net.PortUnreachbaleException. By the way, there is no need to use selectors right, as I have only one Sender and only one Receiver. Any idea about why I get an exception ? channel.isConnected() returns "true" in case of an IP address but channel.write(buffer) or channel.send(buffer,address) give this exception.

Comment: @Aditya UDP connect does nothing on the network, so it can never actually fail, unless the arguments are invalid, e.g. 0.0.0.0. Remove the host parameter when binding: just bind to the port. That binds you to 0.0.0.0, which means all interfaces.